# renameTo returns true but creates new folder android

Tags: java, android, file, file-rename

I'm trying to rename a gallery folder this is method I use:

```
public static void createImageFolder(String newName, String oldName) {
        File oldFolder = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/".concat(oldName));
        File wallpaperDirectory;
        if (!oldFolder.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/".concat(newName));
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
        } else {
            if (!newName.equals(oldName)) {
                wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/".concat(newName));
                boolean x = oldFolder.renameTo(wallpaperDirectory);
                System.out.println(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

when I debug my code I find `x` value is equal to true that means it renamed successfully as expected.

but, when I go to gallery folder I found it not renamed and new images are added to new folder and old folder keep as it.

so can anyone help me please in that?

Edit 1: I tried to wrap it in `Handler` but not worked too.

Comment: `, when I go to gallery folder` ? How are you going to a gallery folder? You should use a file explorer app on your device. Not the Gallery app. Not your pc. Strange you name the Pictures folder a gallery folder to begin with.

Comment: sorry, but,  I misunderstand you. I use word gallery to go my created folder is that what you mean?

Comment: Please reread my comment and then answer to the point.

Comment: the process is on the android phone so I've to use my gallery app there is no need for PC.
what I currently doing is capture image, apply process on it and save in folder say a name `myFolder`

Comment: You did not answer my questions. And in no way you should use a Gallery app.

Comment: really, I misunderstand you what you mean bro?